# Is this disk defective?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, 15.10

I try to attach a USB external disk drive to my Ubuntu laptop (running 15.10), but it doesn't show up. The disk may be defective, but how can I tell for sure?
The drive is a Seagate Barracuda 3Tb disk in a RaidSonic Icy Box IB-351Stu-3B enclosure, which is the brand name for an ASMedia AS2115 USB device.
When I power up the drive, it gets recognized, as seen in `dmesg`:

```
[  720.384062] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  720.517875] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153
[  720.517882] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  720.517888] usb 2-1: Product: AS2115
[  720.517892] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: ASMedia
[  720.517896] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 00000000000000000000
[  721.070744] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  721.073220] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[  721.074233] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  721.078617] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  722.072763] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ASMT     2115             0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  722.073315] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  722.078482] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[  723.080037] ........ready
```

And `lsusb -v` can see bits of it, too:

```
jos@zyrrup:~$ lsusb -v -s 002:012

Bus 002 Device 012: ID 174c:1153 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM2115 SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x174c ASMedia Technology Inc.
  idProduct          0x1153 ASM2115 SATA 6Gb/s bridge
  bcdDevice            0.01
  iManufacturer           2 
  iProduct                3 
  iSerial                 1 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

But the drive is not recognized by `gparted` or any other disk utility.

Should I conclude that the drive is defective, or do I need to install any  special drivers for it?

EDIT: when connected to a Windows machine, the device is recognized (and a driver for it is installed from somewhere), but then Windows offers to format the disk, then fails with something like "formatting failed" with no further information. I wouldn't know how to begin to debug that, and anyway I want to use the drive on a Linux computer.

EDIT2: even though the device claims to be USB 3.0 compatible, I have connected it to an ordinary USB 2.0 port.

Comment: @DavidFoerster all of the methods listed in that answer rely on a device descriptor `/dev/sdc` being available. I didn't get to that stage. Therefore, I don't think this was a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the disk with another one and this time the disk was recognized and could be formatted. The large Barracuda must have been defective. I will close this question in a little while.